# How would I repair this dc motor?

Tags: motor, soldering, wiring

[image]

As you can see the left copper hook thing has snapped. Is there anything I can do to repair it so i can connect it to a wire. Would soldering work?

Comment: Looks as if there's still enough metal there to solder a wire onto.

Comment: You should be able to just solder a wire to what is left of the lug.

Comment: Ninjaed by the DigitalNinja.

Comment: http://s3.postimg.org/kappu3efn/14513754_1188147504591376_688194388_o.jpg

Comment: How strong is solder?

Comment: It looks like a somewhat standard size - have you browsed ebay for replacements?

Answer (score 1):

Soldering does work, but you should work fast. Those "copper" tabs usually extend inside to form the brush connections to the armature. The white plastic end-piece trapping the two tabs is vulnerable to melting from soldering heat. This then releases mechanical pressure from brush-to-armature. The result is an "open-circuit" and the motor fails to turn.

Answer (score 1):

Soldering works - with cautions as as glen_geek says.

Obtain some MULTICORE coper wire - diameter of wire **about** same as thickness  as "leg" on motor tab. This is just a guide - thicker OK as long as soldering and bending work.

Brush wire strand with well tinned soldering iron to deposit solder on wire but not make too inflexible.

Wind wire around broken tab 2 or 3 times - ensure some of tab is still easily accessible to solder.

IF you have solder flux available use a little on the tab-wire join.
Soldering without flux will usually work but flux makes soldering easier.
Acid flux: People usually say DO NOT use acid flux on electronics. Only think about doing this if tab REALLY will not take solder.
Best not used.
IF that was all that was available a small drop here may help with lots of wet brushing afterwards. BUT should work without flux.

Attach wire beyond joint temporarily mechanically to motor in some way so wire to motor connection cannot move - you could sticky tape wire to motor or wind around motor a few times or ... . NB: This is just temporary to give mechanical  stability while soldering.

Use 60/40 'wire" solder.  Thinner is good. DO NOT use "bar" solder.

Apply soldering iron tip - flattest part - to wire outer surface on tab and simultaneously apply solder to wire at iron-tip to wire boundary.
This is NOT what most books say. Ignore the books, listen to me :-).

As soon as solder melts and flows remove iron but keep joint/motor/wire steady until cool or 10 seconds - whichever is longer.

IF you used acid flux (hopefully not) use a wet toothbrush or similar to brush all area where flux MAY have been deposited. Clean brush and repeat several times. Do not re-use tooth brush for tooth brushing :-).

Trim wire at suitable distance from motor and solder final wire to this wire.

Insulate joins and terminals with tape or sleeving or ... .

QED
[image]